# Turn dataframe with 2 columns and 5 rows into dataframe with 5 columns and 1 row

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 2 columns: name and value:

```
name               value
received            63
received.tod        12
received.daybf      50
mantioned           workings
houses              located
```

I want to turn it into this:

```
received   received.tod     received.daybf    mantioned       houses
   63           12               50            workings      located
```

So as you see values from first column became columns, and values from second column became values in those columns accordingly. How could i do that?

Comment: You can use `library(tidyr)`, then `spread(df, name, value)`, or `pivot_wider(df)`, where `df` is your data frame.

Comment: Note that your `value` column contains both string and integer values, so all the new columns will be of type character - you may want to convert the columns with integers to type numeric, depending on what you want to do with the data.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do something like this:

```r
dat <- data.frame(name = c('a', 'b', 'c'),
                  value = c(63, 12, 'workings'))
as.data.frame(as.list(dat$value), col.names=dat$name)
#>    a  b        c
#> 1 63 12 workings
```

Comment: Thanks! I like this slightly better, so I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

using data.table:

```
DT <- data.table(name = c('received', 'received.tod', 'received.daybf', 'mantioned', 'houses'),
                 value = c('63', '12', '50', 'workings', 'located'))

dcast(DT, . ~ name, value.var = 'value')
```

Output:

```
   .  houses mantioned received received.daybf received.tod
1: . located  workings       63             50           12
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(name = c('received', 'received.tod', 'received.daybf', 'mantioned', 'houses'), value = c(63, 12, 50, 'workings', 'located'))

tmp <- data.frame(matrix(df$value, nrow = 1))
names(tmp) <- df$name
```